# HTML form action search, one text box, 2 buttons, 2 possible results

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying these days to do a search form that sends to two different pages with two different buttons with a single text box. So far I am doing this:

```
<form action="http://www.youtube.com/results" method="get">
<input name="search_query" type="text" maxlength="128" />
<input type="submit" value="YouTube" />
</form>

<form action="https://torrentz.eu/search" method="get">
<input name="q" type="text" maxlength="128" />
<input type="submit" value="TorrentZ" />
</form>
```

of course the result is this:

[image: nice and clean]

I can work with that, but I want to make it "cuter" like this:

[image: nice and clean]

So far I have tried using a script but I did not get it so I scraped it, then I tried making an `if`/`elseif` but yet again, I was not sure what I was doing, I am not a good planner for what I see, a toggle button or a dropbox is not as fast, as I just need to press tab once or twice and enter to just search where I want.

As an extra note, I am just making my personal "new tab" for chrome, as the basic and the ones I find in extensions are pretty heavy for my mini laptop.

Comment: use javascript to link a button to the url and pass data to it. Also you should use `post` request and not `get` for sending the query.

Answer (score 3):

In `HTML5` you can use `formaction` attribute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input name="search_query" type="text" maxlength="128" />
      <input type="submit" formaction="http://www.youtube.com/results" value="YouTube" />
      <input type="submit" formaction="https://torrentz.eu/search" value="TorrentZ" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is just two buttons, not sure how to use then, gonna see.

Comment: Edit - I have added a text input too. Put this code in some html file and double click on that file.

Comment: hmm, I try doing the same before but did not work, i notice i did not make it into a form, thank you. Edit: i notice that still use "search_query" for both, while youtube does work, torrentz use only a "q", so it does not work there, so is still halfway.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tried and failed a script, let's look at ways we can achieve this.

## Using `form`

Be extremely wary of what you do here. It is easy to send a `get` request using `form` but it always "flushes" out the query strings already present in the action URL, and submits the request by adding name-value pairs in its child nodes. Make sure to create your query as a child node.

```
<input type="text" id="box" name="searchbox" maxlength="128" placeholder="Type text to be searched here" autofocus />
<input type="button" value="Youtube" onclick="search_youtube()"/>
<input type="button" value="Torrentz" onclick="search_torrentz()"/>
<script>
   function search_youtube(){
    var add="https://www.youtube.com/results";       
    var box = document.getElementById("box");
    box.name="search_query"
    if(box.value)
    {
        var form = open().document.createElement("form");
        form.action=add;
        form.appendChild(box.cloneNode(false))
        form.submit();
    }
   } 

  function search_torrentz(){
    var add="https://www.torrentz.com/search";             
    var box = document.getElementById("box");
    box.name="q"
    if(box.value)
    {
        var form = open().document.createElement("form");
        form.action=add;
        form.appendChild(box.cloneNode(false))
        form.submit();
    }
  }
</script>
```

## Using HTML5 `formaction` attribute

```
<form action="https://www.youtube.com/results" method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="box" name="search_query" maxlength="128" placeholder="Type text to be searched here" autofocus />
    <input type="submit" value="Torrentz" formaction="https://www.torrentz.com/search" onclick="document.getElementById('box').name='q'" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Youtube" />
</form>
```

Comment: The buttons do nothing, maybe is missing something.

Comment: @manuelvillarroel Thank you for letting me know! I have updated the answer. Let me know if this helped.