# Search Wordpress Site and External (Non-Wordpress) Site Search Form with Radio Buttons

Tags: wordpress, search

I'm trying to duplicate the search box on this site : [https:clearviewlibrary.org](https://news.clearviewlibrary.org.) over on a Wordpress install here: [https://news.clearviewlibrary.org](https://news.clearviewlibrary.org.)

I was able to get the search box to execute a search on the external site with this code:

```
<div>
<form method="get" action="javascript:void(0)" 
onsubmit="window.open('http://www.wsld.info/#section=search&term<%=Config%>#section=search&term='+this.term.value+'', '_blank');return true;">
<label>
<input type="text" class="searchform" name="term" placeholder="Search Our Catalog" /></label>
</form>
</div>
```

but I'm stumped on how to go about adding the additional search functionality and radio buttons.

I've tried taking the code from the clearviewlibrary.org site, but that didn't work. I also saw this, but would rather not have the two buttons : [HTML form action search, one text box, 2 buttons, 2 possible results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873005/html-form-action-search-one-text-box-2-buttons-2-possible-results)

Thanks,
Brad